# Where to find a list of participants in The Crusades?

Tags: middle-ages, crusades

I am curious as to where a compiled list of participants in The Crusades exist and how would one access this, particularly of European Crusaders but would find it interesting of any records of both sides of The Crusades as well.

I have always been under the assumption that due to the time period, the chaos, lack of literacy, record keeping, printing press, and decay and destruction of records that not much would exist.

Then I came across this article ["Who Went on the Albigensian Crusade?"](http://ehr.oxfordjournals.org/content/128/534/1047.full) in the English Historical Review (Powers, English Historical Review, 2013) and it stating *"Many deeds recorded grants, pledges or leases of property that were directly related to the crusade"* and it got me wondering what other records would exist for each of the crusades.

I would expect there would at minimum be some records or organizers of groups and perhaps something like "John Smith and 3 swordsmen joined the campaign of so and so.." in addition to the records above as well.

So what I am looking for is a ** research resource(s) of an electronic compiled list of 'known' participants** *(not expecting a list of every participant)* of The Crusades and any other individual participant information.

As from the article above it implies such as list is definitely possible and there are already sites like [Medieval Soldiers](http://medievalsoldier.org/search.php) and [Medieval Genealogy](http://www.medievalgenealogy.org.uk/index.html) though the Crusades basically predate the sites but they do have some information from them.

Does anyone know where such compiled list is available?

Comment: You expect a lot for Middle Ages bureaucrats, who were very thin on the ground.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this question does not fit within our guidelines. First of all, you ask for a list, and second of all, you ask for a reference that would take site visitors away from this site. Lastly, what you are asking is far too broad to be answered on this site. As a result, I am going to have to close the question. If you would like to reword it and maybe ask something more specific, then we can consider reopening.

Comment: @StevenDrennon I can reword but I am not looking for a list but a resource to perform further research. On several other SE sites this is acceptable to seek assistance with research methods. Under the criteria you just stated many of the less specific and poorly worded and those asking for pure unsourced personal opinion should also probably be closed out.

Comment: I totally agree, and over time we will eventually get them cleaned up. Yours just happened to be at the top of the queue when I logged on this evening. Sorry! Please keep in mind that we want questions that can be answered here on this site, and not by sending people away to other sites. Yours is still the latter even after the edit. If you were to narrow it down by asking for an example of some notable dignitaries who participated in a specific Crusade, that would be much more appropriate.

Comment: @StevenDrennon I think it's ironic that you state "then we can consider reopening" when by all appearances you unilaterally put it on hold. Please note, I do not disagree with your decision.

Comment: If the question were to be reworded as "Has there been records of people participating in the crusades?"...

Comment: @Rajib, that would be a little bit better, but still rather iffy, because most answers would probably be just links to another site, especially since he is asking for "electronic", which I take to mean online, and we try to discourage questions that result in those types of answers. Even if he were to ask for a list of books or examples of books, that goes against the guidelines as well. It really needs to be asking something specific and not asking for references or lists.

Comment: @StevenDrennon Fair enough, I also do not want to spam forum with a dozen or more focused questions all attempting to find a similar answer but for specific people or periods or crusades. I'll think about it more I guess and take my question on why Historiography as well as Opinion questions are allowed but research methods / assistance is not to Meta.